# Close a file before invoking File.WriteAllBytes?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, pdf

I have an Windows Forms application that stores PDF files as byte arrays in the database (not my first choice, but I didn't set up the database...). I want the user to be able to view one of these stored files by clicking a basic "view document" button.

With the code I have right now, the bytes are written to a file on disk, then opened using an external process (default PDF reader on user's machine). The problem is that if they click the "view document" button again before closing the file, an exception is thrown because an open file can't be overwritten.

Since I've used Process.Start() to open the file, I've tried various ways of killing the process, but I can't find a way to get the process by the filename (rather than whatever reader program opens the file, which is unknown to the app).

The relevant code inside the click handler is basic:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("document.pdf", PDFBytes)
Process.Start("document.pdf")
```

(PDFBytes is the byte array, document.pdf is just the path I'm using to store the file before it's opened. It'll get overwritten every time the user clicks the "view document" button, which is fine).

Expected result: user can click "view document" to open the PDF multiple times, and the file will close and reopen with each subsequent click without problems.

Actual result: first click opens the document just fine, next click (without closing the file first) throws "System.IO.IOException: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

Comment: Is there a reason that you're always writing the document to the same path instead of using something like [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.gettempfilename?view=netframework-4.8) to save the file?

Comment: Not really! I wasn't aware of that method, for one thing. I do like the idea that the file would get replaced every time instead of saving a new temporary file, but @dbasnett gave me some good ideas for cleaning that up (below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the issue this might help

```
    Dim tempFileName As String
    Dim pathToFile As String
    Try
        tempFileName = IO.Path.GetTempFileName
        pathToFile = IO.Path.ChangeExtension(tempFileName, "pdf")
        IO.File.WriteAllBytes(pathToFile, PDFBytes)
        Process.Start(pathToFile)
        IO.File.Delete(tempFileName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'todo
    End Try
```

edit:

delete old pdfs

```
    Dim tdir As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(tdir)
    Dim fis() As IO.FileSystemInfo = di.GetFileSystemInfos
    Dim ctDel As Integer = 0
    For Each fi As IO.FileSystemInfo In fis
        If fi.CreationTime.AddDays(28) < Date.Now Then 'older than 28 days
            Try
                If fi.Extension = ".pdf" Then
                    IO.File.Delete(fi.FullName)
                    ctDel += 1
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                'todo
                ' Stop
            End Try
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Wonderful, that works beautifully!  I'm pretty new to coding in general and especially VB, so I had no awareness of those IO.Path methods at all. Will have to remember that!  Cheers :)

Comment: Actually, one question, though... is this saving a bunch of randomly-named PDFs to a temporary folder in the app directory and then not cleaning them up?  I notice you're calling IO.File.Delete on the tempFileName and not the pathToFile... I don't want a folder to just fill up with PDFs.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @DerekRutter - you are correct, they aren't being removed automatically.  You could include some code to delete pdf files in the temp directory.

Just love downvotes without explanation.

Comment: Great, thank you!  I'll implement something like that, too.  Really appreciate the help - I would upvote you, but I'm so new to this that I guess stackoverflow won't let me yet...